# Error _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20) after receiving remote notification on CloudKit record addition

Tags: ios, cloudkit

When I receive a remote notification on a record addition (didReceiveRemoteNotification called), I get the following error message:

> _BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)

I've already tried to find out more about this in forums and via Google but I could not find any helpful advice that applies to my situation.

What does the error message mean? What can I do about it?

Comment: Xcode 7 I guess? Well, happened to me without any remote notifications.

Comment: From this post it seems to be CoreSpotlight: http://blog.couldhll.com/2015/08/18/ios9-beta5-extension下调用corespotlight失败/, and here is another stack overflow question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341851/bsmacherror-xcode-7-beta

Answer (score 13):

I just experienced this error. I was in a `UIAlert` Action block; when the block exited the error occurred (BTW the parent `UIAlertViewController` was created in a `dispatch_async block` so was I guess off main thread.

Anyway, I wrapped the action code itself in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       [self handleActionForElement:thisType];



    });
```

and error went away.  Your mileage may vary!

Comment: Did you had a delay between the moment when your action block executes and when you get the hand back on the app?

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 5, I ended up with:

```
func alertAction() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
     //perform code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, I had the same issue on swift

So I've resolved it by putting code in main thread

```
func alertAction() {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //perform code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue.
I was trying to present a custom view on top of a presented view controller of third party framework.

Resolved by moving the presentation logic to my view controller