# _BSMachError XCode 7 Beta

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I am getting the following error when I am running my code in Xcode7 with Swift2, after presenting a view controller through a push segue:

```
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```

The other SO articles had no resolution, does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: I got the same problem running Xcode Version 7.0 (7A218).  Too early to find a pattern; just noticed it.

Comment: Same here... got it now for the first time after setting a breakpoint in viewDidDisappear

Comment: Same here, using Objc in Xcode 7.0 (7A220).

Comment: Same here, getting the problem on Xcode 7 GM

Comment: I also get the same warning using obj c in Xcode 7. How to solve it ?

Comment: I can also consistently reproduce this error by rotating the screen while the on-screen keyboard is up. Xcode 7.0.1, iOS 9.0.2.

Comment: I also have the same issue. No pattern yet. Comes and goes. Not consistent.

Comment: Well, i got the same problem, Xcode 7.1.1, Swift 2.1

Comment: I'm getting it in Version 7.2  (not beta) when I rotate my iPhone 6 iOS 9.2. I have two webViews on screen, and am not using the network (at the time of the error). My webViews don't seem to draw as fast, it's not noticeable, but I have some Javascript that measures various things that reports incorrect results at around the same time this error occurs.

Comment: I got this message when I present a view inside alertView handler block .

Comment: I got same error when appear keyboard, my xcode version is Xcode 7.3.1(7D1014). and my project is based on phonegap, jquery mobile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although this problem seems to persist as a bug and will likely be fixed, it stems from the new **App Transport Security** that has been implemented in iOS 9.

If your application pulls data from a web server, in order to populate the View Controller that you will be presenting, you can resolve these ***errors*** by verifying/granting access to the particular site(s) you're pulling from.

#### In order to address this you will add the following to your App's .plist file:

- You may want to alter your **ATS Exception Dictionary** to fit your needs

  ```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
      <dict>
          <key>testdomain.com</key>
          <dict>
              <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
              <false/>
              <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
              <false/>
              <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
              <true/>
              <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
              <string>TLSv1.2</string>
              <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
              <false/>
              <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
              <true/>
              <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
              <string>TLSv1.2</string>
              <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
              <false/>
          </dict>
      </dict>
  </dict>
  ```

More details to this solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9) or [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)
The Apple Documentation for [**App Transport Security**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/) is worth reading too.

Comment: I've made a simple test app that has no network activity whatsoever, still getting this error. Seems like it has something to do with core layout functionality. Your answer seems irrelevant.

Comment: @NKorotkov the error may spawn from multiple scenarios, see Mark L's answer

Answer (score 17):

I had the same two error messages. In my case, the errors were appearing when I called `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]` after the user selected a button in an open `UIAlertController`.  I assumed the alert was trying to close at the same time I was trying to open the URL. So, I introduced a slight delay and the error message went away.

```
dispatch_after(0.2, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
});
```

Not sure if this helps with your particular problem, but I thought it might be helpful to share.

Comment: This handled the problem for me. I was displaying a PDF using the documentInteractionController and adding the delay made the error go away. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change the Localization native development region key in your info.plist from en to United States

Comment: or United Kingdom :)

Answer (score 3):

Dismissing view controller prematurely might cause this.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; 
//<do something..>
```

This throws _BSMachErrors

vs

```
//<do something..>
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Now, the _BSMachError is gone.

Answer (score 2):

I got these errors when I was using the keyboard. According to this note in Apple Docs, this is somewhat expected.

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Keyboard/0.3.0/

Comment: I don't think these are the Apple Docs, but docs of a third-party.

Comment: true, this is generated using CocoaDocs, which looks similar to Apple's documentation but is user generated. It is in reference to a specific app designed by Bell App Lab

Answer (score 2):

I make like that

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in
        AnswersDataServerEntity.saveSingleDocoment(doc)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Having this statement right below IBAction Button was causing the issue.

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

The issue was fixed in Swift 3,  by commenting out the above line and handling the end editing in a different way, or can also be fixed adding the above line after all other code under IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while debugging and it disappeared when I removed a breakpoint in my response to the view size changing.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For future reference, please try to post additional questions like this in the comments section, as this is not actually a solution. Thanks