# Google signIn XPC connection interrupted xcode 7.2?

Tags: ios, google-signin

[image]

XPC connection interrupted
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32341851/bsmacherror-xcode-7-beta

Comment: i try this but its not working.

Comment: first time its working fine and when i logout from my app and login at that time i face this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me is that there are two storyboards, the main storyboard and the launchScreen storyboard. If you go to the top left of Xcode and click on the Xcode file, it will bring you to a screen about the file. You then scroll to deployment info and switch the main interface to whichever storyboard you use. 
Here is a picture: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLpMk.png)