# Error when putting value from a button

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

The code is working just fine on simulator iphone6, iphon5 and device iphone 5s, throw this error on a device iphone 5c, have no idea why, try to dig into it looking on google and stuff but there was not much explanation about the error itself

so here is the error :

```
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)
_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid name (15)
```

and the code responsable for it :

```
func test()
{
    let newWordPrompt = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: "test", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    newWordPrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "test"
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad

    }
    newWordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
    newWordPrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if let textField = newWordPrompt.textFields?.first
        {
            self.digitsOnlyTextField = textField

        }
        let value = jint(self.digitsOnlyTextField.text!)
        let myvar = myfunc(int: value!)
        javaToOjbcFunc(myfunc, true)
    }))
    presentViewController(newWordPrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Does someone actually know what throw this error?
Already changed the "Localization native development region" in info.plist, didn't change anything.

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31720133/error-bsmacherror-os-kern-invalid-capability-20-after-receiving-remote-not

Comment: Hum, wrapping my action block inside a dispatch_async fixed the display of the error but i still have to wait until i can get the control again.
Might be a thread issue