# UITableView apparently crashing with _BSMachError

Tags: uitableview, ios10

I am receiving the following errors in iOS 10 between calls to `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection)` and `tableView(_:cellForRowAt)` for a `UITableView` that is backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`:

```
<Time> <MyApp>[<Id>] [Common] _BSMachError: port 1407; 
  (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
<Time> <MyApp>[<Id>] [Common] _BSMachError: port 1407; 
  (os/kern) invalid name (0xf) "Unable to deallocate send right"
```

At his point, the app uses only UIKit, Core Data and `URLSession`, i.e. nothing [fancy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39677402/1789384).

What could be the reason why, and how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has now "somehow" disappeared. The layout of the `UITableView` was previously underspecified. I've now added additional constraints to ensure proper layout, and this *may* have effected the root cause as well.

Answer (score 0):

After about 3 hours of beating my head on keyboard and trying different suggestions, I just rewrote the code section. I didn't change anything, just deleted and reinputed, after then everything was fine. Which leads me to believe it's a bug is XCode or the Swift compiler. But to those who might run across this issue, your port number may be different, but before you spend a lot of time hunting for what's wrong, just try rewriting the code and see if that does it for you. Aside from that changing the Localization in the info.plist seems to be the "most" popular answer, although for me and quite a few others that didn't work.