# Cordova iOS: Screen turns blank after cordova-file usage

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ipad

I am currently creating an app using Cordova. While everything works fine under Android, I got a strange bug in the iOS version.

When I open a file on the device the app previously downloaded using `cordova-file`-plugin, the file is shown as intended. When I then click on "Done" in the top left corner, the screen turns fully while instead of showing the app again.
The strange part is that when I am turning the device (landscape to portait) the app is shown. Seems like rotating the device triggers some kind of repaint or something?

While debugging in XCode I get the following message:

> Error '_BSMachError: port 1607; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) “Unable to insert COPY_SEND” [...]

But unfortunately I am not able to debug the app as I do not know any Objective C.

I found [this question previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676762/error-bsmacherror-port-1607-os-kern-invalid-capability-0x14-unable-to-i) but all of the stuff they suggested does not seem to work.

I am using the following versions:

- XCode: 9.1
- iOS: 11.1.X
- Cordova: 7.1.0

My device is an iPad Air 2.
I already tried the usual stuff like removing the platform from Cordova and re-adding it.

I hope someone has an idea of what causes this issue or at least what I can do to work around it.